# PHP: problems searching text in a file

Tags: php

I think i was doing halfway good to get this to halfway work. Anyways the following code works to find it on the first line, but i have a script that creates each on an individual line.
Please revise or create a completely new version of the following to make it to search for the form data on every line.

```
$search = $_POST['search'];
$file = file("SLIST.txt");
foreach($file as $line) 
{
    $line = trim($line);
    if($line == $search) 
    {
        echo $search . " WAS found in the database";
    }
    else 
    {
        echo $search . " was NOT found in the database";
    }
}
```

by form i mean there is a search form on the previous page. This page is the page where it tells you whether the text put into the search form matches a line in the file (ex: Line 1: BOOT Line 2: Tree Search entry: Tree  Echo msg: Tree WAS found in the database.)

It is currently not working like i intended.

Comment: your code seems to be correct, please make sure, that the contents of `$search` and `$file` are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to know if the search string was in the file, and don't care on which line, then `strpos()` ([doc](http://php.net/strpos)) with `file_get_contents()` might be for you like this:

```
$file = file_get_contents('SLIST.txt');
$search = $_POST['search'];

if (strpos($file,$search)){
    echo $search . " WAS found in the database";
}
else 
{
    echo $search . " was NOT found in the database";
}
```

If you want to know the line, your solutions should work as well if you change the `if($line == $search)` with my `strpos()`.

If the line has to be **exactly** the search query you are looking for, then your solution should work just fine

Comment: This appears to work. Added 3 lines to the TXT and it gets every line but the first. Good enough. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

It isn't so clear. I suppose the following is what you wanted.

```
<?php
$search = $_POST['search'];
$file = file("SLIST.txt");
$found = false;
foreach($file as $line) {
  $line = trim($line);
  if($line == $search) {
    $found = true;
    break;
  }
}

if ($found)
{
  echo $search . " WAS found in the database";
}
else {
  echo $search . " was NOT found in the database";
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to find a single string in an entire file. i know you want to look on every line but this is more efficient.
Try this

```
 $file = file_get_contents("SLIST.txt");
if(strpos($file, $search)) 
{
 echo $search . " WAS found in the database";
}
 else {
  echo $search . " was NOT found in the database";
}
```

If you just want to read lines then do

```
if(strpos($line, $search))
{
 echo "found";

}
else 
{
 echo "not found";
}
```